# SQL Server : how to always query a table that has the current date in it's name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, tablename

I am on a database that always creates a report table with a name of `Table_Name_YYYYMMDD`.

I would like to create a query that using a subquery like:

```
Select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112)
```

Could allow me to always get the results from table with the current date in the name.

The user has read-only access to the database.

I did try the following:

```
Declare @Tname varchar(50); 
Set @Tname = 'table_name_' + (Select convert(varchar, getdate(), 112));

Declare @Q varchar(200);
Set @Q = 'Select * From ' + @Tname;

Exec @Q;
```

But I get an error :

> Must declare the scalar variable "@Q".

Thanks!

Comment: Your life and your code would be a lot simpler if you used just one table and added a column for the date.

Comment: *Performance* would be a lot better if you used a single table with an indexed date column. You could use partitions (available in all editions since SQL Server 2016SP1) to manage data if you have millions of rows of data. This would allow you to quickly delete old data simply by removing a partition, or move data between similar tables by switching partitions from one table to another in milliseconds

Comment: As for the error itself, the syntax coloring shows what's wrong. You missed a quote.

Comment: I agree with you folks, but this is a DB from third-party app and I do not have this option. @Panagiotis this, the missing quote, was a typo from me writing the question in the DB it was correct.

Comment: @brunoff does any of those tables contain a date/datetime column that matches the date in the name? If so, you could use a view to combine all tables into one. If the date column has a constraint that prevents incorrect values, the query optimizer will be able to pick the correct table automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not very clear... 
You seem to know, that the approach with *value-named* table names is a bad one. But you told us, that you have to stick to this third-party tool. Well, shit happens ;-)

Your code should work, but assumably you don't show everything and/or you tried to shorten it for brevity (which is great!), but - maybe - you shortened the error away...

Try this:

```
USE master;
GO
CREATE DATABASE testTbWithDate; --Some extra database to create tables
GO
USE testTbWithDate;
GO
CREATE TABLE SomeName_20190701(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
GO
CREATE TABLE SomeName_20190630(ID INT,SomeValue VARCHAR(100));
GO
--test values
INSERT INTO SomeName_20190630 VALUES(1,'this is 30th of June'); 
INSERT INTO SomeName_20190701 VALUES(1,'this is 1st of July');
GO
```

--Here starts the query

```
--You should always use (n)varchar together with a length parameter
--And you should not keep your length to small...
Declare @Tname varchar(50) =  --<-- 50 might be not enough...
   'SomeName_' + (Select convert(varchar(8), {d'2019-07-01'}, 112)); --I added "(8)"


Declare @Q varchar(max); --This was pretty small, I use "(max)"
Set @Q = 'Select * From ' + QUOTENAME(@Tname); --I use QOUTENAME to avoid invalid names and help (a little bit) against SQL injection

PRINT @Q; --always print out your command. Now you can copy and paste it into a query window and check the syntax.
Exec(@Q); --the execution
```

--Clean-Up

```
GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE testTbWithDate;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Shnugo. The issue seems not to be in the query, though I did increase the variable sizes. I just figured out that the issue might be a bug in mssql-cli for OSX. I just tried the same query using the grafana query explorer and it just worked. Any way, I really appreciate your instructions as they provided opportunities for me to improve my own approach to query problem solving. Learned  a lot from this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the table name itself to store somewhat transient information is not best practice.  It would be better to just maintain a *single* report table, and then add a timestamp/datetime column for the date of the report (along with some kind of primary key).

Then, if you wanted to select all records pertaining to today's report, you could just use:

```
SELECT *
FROM ReportTable
WHERE dt = GETDATE();  -- or something similar to this
```

Comment: This is a third party Application DB I do not have this option, but agree with your point.

Answer (score 1):

First, `Exec @Q` is the syntax for calling a stored proc. 
Use

```
Exec (@Q);
```

to exec a statement.

Comment: The missing quote in the question was my bad while typing the query here. the query in the DB has correct quotes. I did edit the question include the quote, thanks for informing. :)
Still even using the Exec (@Q); I am getting the error must declare scalar variables. I am wandering if this can be due to the user is read-only privilege in the DB, but it shoud appear in the error that user has no provilege.

Comment: I wonder if any other line of code missing, `go` or something? Your code doesn't produce the `missing variable` error.  Removed unrelevant phrase from the answer.